# Pivot table; remove old values from slicer

Tags: excel

I have two pivot tables that are connected with a slicer.
The slicer is used to set the date on both pivot tables.

The problem is that it keeps showing old values that are not in the data anymore.
On one of the files (I have four similar files) I have deleted everything that is newer than 2016-05-09, but still the slicer is showing other dates that month.
If I click on them the tables are empty so clearly it can't find any values with those dates.

The old values are written with gray text.
I have tried to find a solution to this issue on google but no luck.
I have tried to update both tables and I have even removed the slicer and then created a new one, but still the old values does not go away.

Anyone have a clue why it's doing this?
Excel 2010.

Comment: Would refreshing the pivot table correct this? Click on it and press Alt+F5, alternatively once selected you will see the 'PivotTable Tools > Options' tab, click the Refresh button on the ribbon.

Comment: see if [this](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot04.html) helps. Also, I VTC as this question is more suited to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @OliverCarr sorry, I meant refresh. My Excel is in Swedish (I hate it) and I translated it incorrectly. When I wrote update I meant refresh. It did not help :-/

Comment: @ScottHoltzman VTC? http://www.acronymfinder.com/VTC.html . I will look at the link on monday, it's on my work computer. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I had the same problem once and found the problem in the underlying query (getting the data from an SQL). The problem was that I was filtering out old data with something like `select * from tblCustomers where LastName like N'H*'`. Afterwards, I expected the slicer to have only names starting with `H`. Yet, the slicer knew that the underlying table had more last names and was (automatically) based on that table. So, I had all the slicer options from the underlying table. Maybe this is the same with you in this case?!

Comment: @Ralph i'm not using SQL but your comment may still be valid. I will have a look at the connection between the data and the pivot table. I will post an update on monday when I'm at work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the slicer.This is to do with the PivotCache  for the PivotTable. If you check the Dropdown filters on the PivotTable , you will also see there is checkboxs for data that is not currently in your dataset.

To change this:-

Right click your PivotTable> PivotTable Options

On the Data Tab , Change "Number of items to retain per field" from `Automatic` to `None` and press `OK`.

Then refresh your PivotTable.  The Filters on the PivotTable and the Slicer will now only show values that are currently in the dataset.

Comment: Thank you! I will look in to this on monday.

Comment: I wonder why 'automatic' is a default for that setting. Why would someone like to see values in the slicer that doesn't exist in the pivot table anymore?